# C#: How to sort and indent XML before saving?

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, c#-4.0, comparison

I am getting responses from two different web services in XML format. Both web services have the same logic but developed in different technologies. We are shifting our web services to Microsoft Technology. The web service engine is the core which is connected to many other application and providing different services to them.

Whenever there is a call to a production web service, we pass a similar call to the web service which is developed on Microsoft Technologies and save both responses in separate folders.

Now, we have to compare both responses (XML). There are lot of sorting and intending issues. I would like to avoid all the sorting and indenting issues so I can get the right comparison report.

> Is there a way you can sort and indent
>   XML before saving (XMLDocument.Save) it?

Thanks.

---

**Solution:**

I have found some XSLT that does that on the net, but there seems to be a
problem when the elements have attributes.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-template select="@* | node()">
            <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Indeed, attribute nodes have to be copied to the result tree before any nodes of another type. Because of the sorting, the node-set loses document order and thus cannot any longer guarantee that the attributes are processed earlier than the elements and text nodes.

one solution is this:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
            <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But since the relative output order of attributes after serialization of the result tree depends on the processor, you might as well omit the attribute sorting:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks Snoopy and others for their help!

Comment: How are you saving the XML data currently? Post some code.

Comment: @dtb through XmlDocument.Save()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i recommend xmlunit for comparing the files, this nunit extension is written in c# and free.
http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/

or do it like this if you prefer manual compares:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("bla");
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("data.xml",null);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
doc.Save(writer);
```

Comment: @Snoppy Thanks. This covers half of the query. Any idea how to sort nodes without knowing XML?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<string, System.Xml.XmlNode> list =
                new SortedDictionary<string, XmlNode>();
            XmlNode node;            
            list.Add("your_sort_key", node);
            foreach (var current in list)
            {
                // write using XML Writer
            }

Answer (score 0):

If you compare using text diff tools, you would need to fix indentation. But if you compare using XML-comparison tools or if you write a tool that iterates over the nodes and compares, then indentation becomes moot.

Look at XML Diff tools such as the one from Altova here: http://www.altova.com/downloadtrialdiffdog.html?gclid=CM-c8ayEzqkCFcNP4Qod4DTKMw

Comment: I am very happy with Beyond Compare 3 Pro (format:=XML Sorted and Tided) for comparing XML. Its just additional difference of sorted and indented which I want to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

If it's differences what you want and you are only concern about the **content it self**, for example, checking if the headers are correctly set, if you are missing any node...

I would strongly suggest to **STOP seeing differences MANUALLY**!

I would **create a simple application** (windows / web) that would read those 2 folders and consume each file name (let's image it's the same name) and make a graphical representation of each node and properties, and, `Assert`ing that everything is in the correct place.

It's easy to do and [you can programmatically check upon new files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) in that directory and process them automatically, generating outputs for example to a `result` directory or even database or email.

- **Open the files** (using `FileSystemWatcher` to avoid doing stuff manually)
- **Parse them** (parse them into custom objects of load them as plain `XMLNodeList`)
- **Compare them** (for each node in the original (old service) file, does the new service file has that?)

Comment: why would I create one? I'm using Beyond Compare and it is very useful for such purpose.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to run both XmlDocuments through the same Xslt (doing the sorting and indenting). The resulting XmlDocuments should be easy to compare (manually) with the tool of your choice.